# Contact Form 7 In-Field-Labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form

I was wondering if someone could assist with an issue I am having with form labels not disappearing when I select the field?

I currently have a Wordpress site where I use the Contact Form 7 plugin for my form creation. I have since used a jQuery code snippet I found to implement some In-field-Labels but for some reason when I click in the fields the label text will not go away?

What am I doing wrong?

http://alanbrandt.com/contact

Please note I am not a developer so sorry if this seems like a stupid question.

Hope someone can help?

Thanks!

ANSWER:

Here is the solution...

```
jQuery(function(){
      $('#commentform')
  .on('mouseenter focus', 'input, textarea', function () {
      $(this).closest('p').find('label:first').css('opacity', 0.5)
  })
  .on('mouseleave focusout', 'input, textarea', function () {
      $(this).closest('p').find('label:first').css('opacity', 1)
  })
  .on('input', 'input', function (e) {
      var label = $(this).closest('p').find('label:first');
      e.target.value == '' ? label.show() : label.hide()
  });
});
```

Comment: You would need to hide it on a onChange event I think.

try to add something like this to your .js 

$('wpcf7-form-control').change(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('label').hide();
});

Comment: To make it easier for us, please post here your snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('form.wpcf7-form').on('keyup','input, textarea',function(){
       jQuery(this).closest('span').prev('label').css('opacity',0);
    });
});
```

**Updated**

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('form.wpcf7-form').on('keyup','input, textarea',function(){
       var opaq=1;
       if($(this).val())
           opaq=0;// if something has written then opacity should be 0
       jQuery(this).closest('span').prev('label').css('opacity',opaq);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks... It works great, instead of keyup is there another option for when selected? click? select??? Thanks again...

Comment: @myatix Yes you can use `focus,click,change` events

Comment: They make the `opacity` to `0.5` instead of `0`

Comment: Yes I can see that, but there is a bit more to it than that. The label also comes back if you don't type anything and select another field? Which in your example it doesn't make the label visible again?

Comment: @myatix test the above answer I've made changes in it.

Comment: Thank you... Strange though because it is only when I press the second key that the label opacity is set to 0? You can see it on my site now...

Comment: You can use `keydown or focus, blur event` to solve this issue.

Comment: The same issue exists with focus, keydown etc etc... It appears as if the code only works the second time it is initiated.

Comment: @myatix You can find all funtions related to your problem and needs on url http://www.adamalex.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.3